# Add an SVG within a Number Input

Tags: html, css, forms, vue.js

I have a Number Input form field.

```
<input type="number" name="" v-model.lazy="userResponse" placeholder="Enter value here" class="bg-white border-gray-300 border-2 text-gray-600 shadow-md px-6 py-4 rounded-lg my-2" :class="{ 'border-teal-500 border-2' : isCorrect }" :disabled="showFeedbackView">
```

It gives me this:

[image]

I would like to add an svg checkmark icon next to the value whenever isCorrect value is true.

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add class `is-correct` with the following rule :

```
.is-correct{
    background-image: url(/path/to/success.svg);
}
```

and use it like :

```
:class="{ 'border-teal-500 border-2 is-correct' : isCorrect }"
```

I inspired the answer from [github new repo page](https://github.com/new)

Comment: Ah yes, I should have done this. I just embedded it into a div and added the SVG with some absolute position.

Comment: Yes put the input and the svg inside a container with a relative position and svg with absolute position then play with right property